# XSLT Template. Blocks/Inlines

Tags: xslt, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to make an xslt template to generate pdf.

How to create a template that can fill data in such way:

http://web13.twitpic.com/img/109586649-2ff71ad3e1ee483df6b9be14dcb3804a.4c0632a8-scaled.png

Comment: Your image link displays nothing

Comment: sorry... here it is... http://twitpic.com/1t8tll

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be not to try to output PDF directly from XSLT, but to transform to an intermediate representation and tool that can do the text layout for you. XSL-FO may be a good choice here, since transforming into it should be straightforward.

To that end, take a look at Apache FOP:

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/index.html

and here's a tutorial that will give you a sense of what you can do with FOP:

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/10/16/fop.html

Hope this helps!